# retrieve data from Sqlite and store into CSV file

Tags: android, csv

im trying to return Data from Database and save it on a file as CSV in SDcard and attach the file and email it, all this works perfect and the Data should be like this on the Excel.

**Example**

COLUMN A...........COLUMN B

123123232..........John

964803400..........Smith

657484738..........Mike

my problem is when i open the Excel the Data is displayed like this

COLUMN A...........COLUMN B

123123232..........

964803400..........

657484738..........

John

Smith

Mike

Here is the code **Names.Java**

```
dbUser.open();

                File root=null;     
             try {  
                    // check for SDcard   
                    root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();                   
                    Log.i(TAG,"path.." +root.getAbsolutePath());  

                    //check sdcard permission  
                    if (root.canWrite()){  
                        File fileDir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath()+"/fun/");  
                        fileDir.mkdirs();  

                        Log.d("PATH",fileDir.toString());

                        File file= new File(fileDir, "itisfun.csv");  
                        FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file);  
                        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(filewriter); 
                        String[] div = dbUser.getVname_Mnumber(sharedUsername1,product).toString().split(",");

                        Log.d(sharedUsername1, product);

                        Log.d("VVVVVVVVVV", dbUser.getVname_Mnumber(sharedUsername1,product).toString());

                        for (int i =0; i<div.length;i++)
                        out.write( div[i] +"\n" );

                        out.close();  
                    }  
                } catch (IOException e) {  
                    Log.e("ERROR:---", "Could not write file to SDCard" + e.getMessage());  
                }
```

Here is my **DBadapter**

```
public String getVname_Mnumber(String date , String Vname) throws SQLException {    

    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{date,Vname}; 

    Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MeterNumber,VendorName FROM " + SCAN_TABLE + " WHERE  Date = ? AND VendorName = ? ",whereArgs);

    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> results1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (mcursor.moveToNext()) {
        results.add(mcursor.getString(0));
        results1.add(mcursor.getString(1));
    }

    return results + ","+ results1;

}
```

will appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're basically creating two ArrayLists - the first only contains column 0 from the Cursor and the second only contains column 1. You then return all of the column 0 results followed by a "," followed by all the results for column 1.

Try a `StringBuilder` for the whole thing. Example...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (mcursor.moveToNext()) {
    sb.append(mcursor.getString(0) + "," + mcursor.getString(1) + "\n");
}
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: i just want it to show this(45488556) on column A and show John on column B but your code is show on the same column?

Comment: Then you are not importing the CSV data correctly. The whole point about CSV is each line represents a data "record" and each column is separated by a comma. If you import the CSV file into Excel correctly, it will show exactly what you want.

Comment: Oh wait. Forget the `split(...)` part of your 'writer' code and just write the whole string returned by `getVname_Mnumber(...)` to your output file.

Comment: im lost. can you please edit my code so that i can see where im doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry I had to rush off and do something so didn't see your previous comment. Glad you've got it working.